# Is it possible to emulate Windows 8 for ARM?

Tags: windows-8, arm, emulation, windows-runtime

I have a few programs I'd really like to test on Windows 8 for ARM. I don't have any Windows 8 ARM hardware though. Is it possible to install Windows 8 in some kind of ARM emulator or some such?

Yes, I know that if it compiles on WinRT it is suppose to "just work", but I'd really like to test it not only to see if it works, but also relative performance(as much can be guessed from an emulator)

Comment: Actually, I think I may have an answer. There is a Windows phone 8 emulator(unreleased?) which I'm about 90% sure uses ARM. My computer isn't capable of running it because it lacks SLAT though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now appears to be sorta possible (haven't tested yet) with the new [App Ceritification Kit for WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/hh852363), which appears to include ARM emulation.

EDIT: This isn't an emulator, it will only run on an ARM WinRT device. I guess there is no ARM emulator, despite that page mentioning ARM and emulation

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, how to start you x86 PC in an "ARM mode", or launch Simulator in ARM mode. WinRT was designed to bridge the differences or these platforms so you don't need to worry about it and you can just develop. All I can think of right now is try to contact local Microsoft representative in your area - if they have any ARM tablet for testing, they might help you in this, but again if your app is not really flawed or computing power demanding, don't worry about the ARM platform :)

Comment: Well, we obfuscate .Net applications. We've found bugs in .Net's JIT compiler before with some of the more funky stuff we do.. That's our only real worry.